# Combine async await with .then in express route

Tags: node.js, express

Is it ok to leave additional none blocking requests to run in the background one each request?

Example code below:

```js
const testHandler = async (req, res) => {
  await fetch() // do the main request

  // the following will be a background task which not going to block the response
  fetch().then(() => {
   // do the test behind the request
  }).catch(e => console.error(e))

  res.send() // send request before the backgroundTask is completed
}
```

Will it cause an issue if I have a background task that gets qued as more requests coming in?

Comment: As promises run within the NodeJs event loop,  it is okay unless the second Promise relies on res or next, which are not valid after the response has been sent.

Comment: @Mr.R so I can't let that promise run in the background? eg task such as sending an email which I don't want to block the response.

Comment: It is okay to let promises run in the background, but be careful to avoid using the response (which might have been sent already), and also, (be aware) it keeps your event loop busy. If there are lots of requests you'll better give Workers a try.

Comment: thank you very much @Mr.R feel free to leave that as answer, i will mark as answered.